# how can I pass null into asp:Parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsLeave" 
                   runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:test %>"
                   SelectCommand="app_leave_notification_select"
                   SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="employee_id" Type="int32" />
    </SelectParameters>                
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Does anyone know how can I pass null into asp:Parameter employee_id?

Answer (score 3):

Add a `ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"` into the Parameter so it would like like:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="employee_id" 
               Type="int32" 
               ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
```

Add pass in an empty string.

I got this from this blog entry: http://www.blog.sumantdubey.com/post/SQLDataSource-Passing-Null-Parameters.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Parameter Name="employee_id" 
               Type="Int32?" 
               ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
```